# Cannot read property '_local' of null

Tags: connectycube

When executing

```
this._session = ConnectyCube.videochat.createNewSession(ids, type, options);
```

I get the following error [Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMujW.jpg)

Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

Please check the Preparations section https://developers.connectycube.com/js/videocalling?id=preparations .

You need to be connected to Chat in order to start calling, because Video Calling API uses the real time Chat as for the signaling transport.